# How to find which step in Dockerfile added some path?

Tags: docker

I have a Docker image which contains a file, say `/usr/bin/foo`. What's the easiest way to find out which step of the Dockerfile added that path? (Which I thought was equivalent to the question, of which layer of the Docker image does that path come from?)

I wrote a script which prints out all the paths in the image, prefixed by layer ID. It appears to work, but is quite slow:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
die() { echo 1>&2 "ERROR: $*"; exit 1; }
dir=$(mktemp -d)
trap "rm -rf $dir" EXIT
img="$1"
[[ -n "$img" ]] || die "wrong arguments"
docker image save "$img" | (cd $dir && tar xf -) ||
    die "failed extracting docker image $img"
(cd $dir && find . -name '*.tar' | while read f; do layer=$(echo $f | cut -d/ -f2); tar tf $f | sed -e "s/^/$layer:/"; done) ||
    die "failed listing layers"
```

(It could be made faster if it didn't write anything to disk. The problem is while `tar tf -` prints the paths in the TAR, it doesn't do the same for the nested `layer.tar` files. I am thinking I could use the Python `tarfile` module - but surely somebody else out there has done this already?)

However, I don't know how to translate the layer ID it gives me to a step in the Docker image. I thought I'd correlate it with the layer IDs reported by `docker inspect`:

```bash
docker image inspect $IMAGE | jq -r '.[].RootFS.Layers[]' | nl
```

But the layer ID which my script reports as containing the path, I can't find in the output of the above command. (Is that a consequence of BuildKit???)

In the end, I gave up on this whole approach. Instead I just made some educated guesses as to which Dockerfile line was probably creating that path, tested each guess by commenting it out (and all the lines after it), and soon I found the answer. Still, there must be a better way, surely? Ideally, what I'd like is something like a `--contains-path=` option to `docker image history` – which doesn't exist, but maybe there is something else which does the equivalent?

Comment: This might already be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317643/can-i-show-data-in-specific-layer-from-an-docker-image-and-how.

Comment: @jcragun that question is about just looking in each layer, this question is more related to searching all the layers for a specific path. Of the two tools mentioned in its answers, one (`dive`) doesn’t appear (from a cursory review of its documentation) to have that feature; the other (`dlayer`) looks more promising (but I haven’t had the chance to try it yet)

Comment: @jcragun Thanks. While it didn't directly answer my question, it was a good starting point

Comment: Happy to help! Really great to see your contribution back, too.

Answer (score 3):

While [dlayer](https://github.com/orisano/dlayer) does not have any searching function built-in, it is straight-forward to implement by combining it with a Perl one-liner:

```bash
docker image save $IMAGE | 
    dlayer -n 999999 |
    perl -ne 'chomp;$query=quotemeta("usr/bin/foo");$cmd=$_ if $_ =~ m/ [\$] /;print "$cmd\n\t$_\n" if m/ $query/;'
```

This will print something like:

```
  13 MB      $ /opt/bar/install.sh # buildkit
     637  B      usr/bin/foo
```

`-n 999999` is to increase limit of number of file names output from the default 100, otherwise the path will only be found if it is in the first 100 from that layer.

(I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/orisano/dlayer/pull/11) to add a built-in search function to dlayer, which removes the need for this one-line Perl script.)